# How to show ratio in the second axis with chart Devexpress

Tags: winforms, charts, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a database

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    name nvarchar(50),
    total int,
    ratio float
);

insert into table1 (name, total, ratio) values ('dream', 1200, 0.15)
insert into table1 (name, total, ratio) values ('SH', 2200, 0.2)
insert into table1 (name, total, ratio) values ('Novo', 1000, 0.35)
```

I would like to show total in the first axis on the left and ration on second axis on the right as below
[image]

pls give me your advise

Answer (score 1):

You have to add [secondary axis](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/6245/controls-and-libraries/chart-control/examples/chart-elements/how-to-add-secondary-axes-to-a-chart).
Something like this:

```
var anotherY = new SecondaryAxisY("Tyle");
((XYDiagram)chartControl1.Diagram).SecondaryAxesY.Add(anotherY);
((LineSeriesView)seriesTyle.View).AxisY = anotherY;
```